# C++ pointer covariance

Tags: c++, pointers, covariance

It never occured to me that c++ has pointer covariance and therefore lets you shoot yourself in the leg like this:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() : a(5) {}
    int a;     
};

struct Child1 : public Base
{
    Child1() : b(7) {}
    int b;
    int bar() { return b;}
};

struct Child2 : public Base
{
    Child2(): c(8) {}
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    Child1 children1[2];

    Base * b = children1;

    Child2 child2;

    b[1] = child2; // <------- now the first element of Child1 array was assigned a value of type Child2

    std::cout << children1[0].bar() <<  children1[1].bar(); // prints 57 
}
```

Is it an undefined behaviour? Is there any way to prevent it or at least have a warning from compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined behavior.

And no, a typical C++ compiler, at this point, is unlikely to be able to identify something that merits a diagnostic, here. But, C++ compilers get smarter with each passing year. Who knows what will be the state of affairs, years from now...

However, a minor quibble:

```
b[1] = child2; // <------- now the first element of Child1 array was assigned...
```

No. That's not the first element. it's the second element. `b[0]` would be the first element. Furthermore, `b` is not an array, it's a pointer. And it's a pointer to a single element. It's not a pointer to a two element array.

And that is where the undefined behavior comes from.

The reason it's not an array is because:

```
Base * b = children1;
```

`children1` decays to a `Child1 *`. If that's where the affair ended, you could say that `b` would be a pointer to a two-element array.

But that's not where the things ended. The decayed pointer was than casted to a `Base *`. You can implicitly cast a pointer to a subclass to a pointer to a superclass. But (loosely speaking now) you cannot cast a pointer to an array of subclasses to an array of superclasses. Hence, `b` is, strictly, a pointer to a single element, and `b[1]` becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm used to calling b[0] the zero element. And actually making an array is not neccessary. I can produce single Child1 child1; Base * b = &child1; *b = child2; and get the same undefined behaviour, can't I?

Comment: No, this would be perfectly defined behavior.

Comment: @Amomum: Of course, just because it's well defined doesn't mean it's a good idea. Nor does it mean that it does what you think it does.

Comment: @Amomum `b[0]` is element zero, but also the first element.  And no, that slice is defined: it just does an `operator=(Base&)`.  This is unlikely to do anything useful, but it is defined.